# From a list of objects, get a character vector of their names

Tags: r, scope, substitution, evaluation, names

I have a function that takes as an argument a list of functions.

```
library(moments)
library(plyr)
tests <- list(mean, varience, skewness, kurtosis)
f <- function(X, tests){
  out   <- each(... = tests)(X)   #each from plyr
  names(out) <- GetNames(tests)
  out
}
```

I want `GetNames` to take the list of objects, in this case functions, and return the names of the objects as text.  Ideally, I'd like `GetNames` to work with any list of named objects:

```
> GetNames(tests)
[1] "mean"     "varience" "skewness" "kurtosis"
```

`as.character(tests)` returns the text of the code of each function, not their names.

I tried:

```
GN <- function(X) deparse(substitute(X))
GetNames <- function(X) lapply(tests, GN)
GetNames(tests)
```

But this returns:

```
[[1]]
[1] "X[[i]]"

[[2]]
[1] "X[[i]]"

[[3]]
[1] "X[[i]]"

[[4]]
[1] "X[[i]]"
```

I have some version of this problem frequently when writing R code. I want a function to evaluate its argument some number of steps, here one step from `tests` to the names of its objects, and then stop and let me do something to the result, here convert them to strings, rather than going on to get the referents of the names before I can grab them (the names).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your general version of the problem, but if this comes up a lot, there may be better ways to accomplish these tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you run

```
tests <- list(mean, varience, skewness, kurtosis)
```

those symbols are evaluated and discarded. If you look at

```
tests[[2]]
```

or something, you can see there really isn't an original reference to `varience`, but rather the funcion that the symbol `varience` pointed to is now stored in a list. (Things work a bit differently when passing parameters to functions thanks to the promises and the call stack but that's not what you're doing here). There is no lazy-evaluation for `list()` after you've run it.

If you want to keep the names of the functions, it's probably best to work with a named list. You can make a helper function like

```
nlist <- function(...) { dots<-substitute(...()); setNames(list(...), sapply(dots, deparse))}
tests <- nlist(mean, var, skewness, kurtosis)
```

Now the values are preserved as names

```
names(tests)
# [1] "mean"     "var"      "skewness" "kurtosis"
```

Comment: Thanks! That is a very effective workaround for what I am trying to do, which is to name the outputs of a list of functions applied to an object with the names of the functions, without having to type everything twice.

Comment: Hey, that works even when nlist() is defined _inside the function_. Excellent!

Answer (score 1):

I confess to being a bit baffled by this question, which makes me think there's some pieces of information you haven't shared with us.

For instance, you say:

> I'd like GetNames to work with any list of named objects

Um...well for a *named* list of objects, such a function already exists, and it's called `names()`.

The "sane" way to do this sort of thing is just name the list in the first place:

```
tests <- list("mean" = mean, "variance" = variance, 
              "skewness" = skewness, "kurtosis" = kurtosis)
```

or you can set the names programmatically via `setNames`.

Comment: I didn;t say a named list, I said a list of named objects. The objects in my example are functions. The functions have names. names(tests) returns NULL. lapply(tests, names) returns a list of five NULLs.  Is it mysterious not to want to type everything twice in a frequently used function?